# Avoid child context override beans from parent context in Spring

Tags: xml, spring

I have the following two xml files in my application. The application context is initialized with parent.xml to start with and is later updated with the child.xml using the code:

```
context = FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(parentContext)
context.setConfigLocations(child xml path)
context.refresh()

parent.xml:
<bean id="cache" class="com.ICache"/>

child.xml:
<bean id="bean1" class="com.Class1">
   <constructor-arg index="0" ref="cache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bean2" class="com.Class2">
   <constructor-arg index="0" ref="bean1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bean3" class="com.Class3">
   <constructor-arg index="0" ref="cache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bean4" class="com.Class4">
   <constructor-arg index="0" ref="bean3"/>
</bean>
```

I now have a use case which requires me to swap the "cache" bean in some of the beans initialized in child.xml and this is what I did:
Added the below config to parent.xml:

```
<bean id="newCache" class="com.ICache"/>
<bean id="bean3" class="com.Class3">
   <constructor-arg index="0" ref="newCache"/>
</bean>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work and I am thinking its because of the order in which the beans are initialized and when there are multiple beans with the same name, the last one wins. Is there a way to not let the parent beans to be overridden by those in the child context ?

Also, is there a way to add conditional logic (ex: if bean defined) in spring configuration ? I would like to know if I can modify some beans in my child.xml to use "newCache" if defined else use "cache".

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use Spring [profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to provide a setter for the cache in Class3:

```
public class Class3 {
  private ICache cache;
  public Class3(ICache cache){..}
  public setICache(ICache cache) {
      this.cache = cache;
  }

}
```

And if you want to swap the cache for Class3 in ClassA (ClassA is the client of Class3) implement ApplicationContextAware and change the cache for Class3:

```
public class ClassA implements ApplicationContextAware {

 @Autowire
 Class3 class3;

 @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    ICache cache = (ICache)applicationContext.getBean("newCache");
    class3.setICache(cache);
  }

}
```

I hope I understood what you are looking for correctly. Otherwise comment on the answer to discuss it.